# How can I setup Fluentlenium to run in different browser drivers?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, fluentlenium

I am trying to run Fluentlenium in different browser drivers. I think I need to configure the getDefaultDriver() from Fluentlenium but I am not exactly sure on how to do that. Any exmaple codes would be great. Here is my code and it's not working. The message I am getting in Eclipse is:

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:107)
    at com.picklist.tests.PicklistCreate.(PicklistCreate.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:195)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

"

My Code below:

```
public WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

// Overrides the default driver
@Override
public WebDriver getDefaultDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromeDriver/chromedriver.exe"); // Set for ChromeDriver
    //return driver;
    return driver;
}
```

If I do the following code, it works but then the driver is no longer defined and I got a ton od code that uses driver.xxx:

```
// Overrides the default driver
@Override
public WebDriver getDefaultDriver() {
    return new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I solved this:

public WebDriver driver;

```
// Overrides the default driver
@Override
public WebDriver getDefaultDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromeDriver/chromedriver.exe"); // Set for ChromeDriver
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks.The driver (.exe file) I got from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Answer (score 1):

There is not `getDefaultDriver` in FluentTest, you can use this code:

```
@Override
public WebDriver newWebDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path-to-chrome-driver/chromedriver");
    Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromeOptions.put("binary", "/usr/bin/chromium-browser");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
    return new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an abstract `createDriver()` function that is overridden by each type of driver.  Each driver should return a correctly configured driver, which is then stored, and returned when you call `getDefaultDriver();`